# Powershell: Cannot index into a null array

Tags: sql-server, powershell, switch-statement

So, I've got an interesting issue...  I've got two Server 2012 boxes set up, one with a default instance of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, and the other with a named instance of SQL Server 2012 Express Edition.  I'm in the process of writing a Powershell script that will audit SQL Server 2012 against the CIS benchmark for SQL Server.

I have the following query, the purpose of which is to retrieve the login mode:

```
$sapwam = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "exec xp_loginconfig 'login mode'" -ServerInstance $InstanceName
```

And then later, I use a switch statement to verify that the setting is configured correctly.  It looks like this:

```
switch ($sapwam.config_value -eq "Windows NT Authentication") {
True {"4.1 Set The Server Authentication Property To Windows Authentication mode:                                    Pass"}
False {"4.1 Set The Server Authentication Property To Windows Authentication mode:                                    Deficient"}
}
```

The part that has me stumped is this:  When I run the script against the Express Edition, everything works out great - no errors.  Whenever I run the script against the Enterprise Edition instance, I get the 'Cannot index into a null valued array' error.  So, in order to see what's going on, I've added a `Write-Host $sapwam.config_value` statement to see what data is contained in the variable, and I've also added a `$sapwam.config_value -eq $null` statement, just to verify that I'm not crazy.  The Write-Host statement will correctly display the value contained in the config_value property, and the boolean evaluation will evaluate correctly (i.e. False).  I've also

Is there something I'm missing?

Edit:

After taking KevinD's suggestion, I added this line `$Error.Exception | Where-Object -Property Message -Like "Cannot index into a null array." | Format-List -Force` to the end of my script... which generates these error details:

```
ErrorRecord                 : Cannot index into a null array.
StackTrace                  :    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : Cannot index into a null array.
Data                        : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException              :
TargetSite                  : System.Object CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object, Int32)
HelpLink                    :
Source                      : Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

Comment: Which line produces the error? After getting the error, try typing "$Error[0].Exception | Format-List -Force" - it may give more details about what's causing it.

Comment: The switch statement is the line that's throwing the error.  For some reason, the $sapwam variable (or $sapwam.config_value) are being evaluated as null in the context of the switch statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Exception details don't really help. It *can* be quite helpful when dealing with SQL exceptions.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a switch? What happens if you replace the switch block with if ($sapwam.config_value -eq "Windows NT Authentication") {...} else {...}? Do you get the same error on the if statement?

Comment: I was using switch statements because they're quick and easy.  I've thought about converting that switch statement into an if/else block, but have been resisting because of my own vanity (it would be the only check formatted as if/else while the others would be switches).  I guess its time to let go of the ugly elegance i've got and go for functionality.

The part that's really got me mystified though is that the error is generated on Enterprise Edition, but not Express.  Wonder what gives.

Comment: And, sure enough, even after converting the switch statement to an if/else block, the error persists.  I've even tried moving the value in the `config_value` property to a new variable forcibly typed as a string and get the same damn error...

Comment: See if this gives the same error: "$s = ($sapwam | Select-Object -First 1).config_value".

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work either...  I'm honestly stumped on this one.